# Как создать проект с версией «compileSdkVersion 22» и «targetSdkVersion 22»?

Tags: android-studio

Как создать проект с версией «compileSdkVersion 22» и «targetSdkVersion 22» и собрать его? Пытался создать данный проект но получаю кучу ошибок, а сам проект не запускается.

14 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
7. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
8. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
9. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-22.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 32.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
10. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-22.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 32.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
11. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-22.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 32.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
12. Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-22.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 32.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
13. Dependency 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-22.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 32.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
14. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-22.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 32.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать проект с версией «compileSdkVersion 22» и «targetSdkVersion 22» в Android Studio, вы должны сделать следующее:

1. Откройте Android Studio и выберите «Create new project».
2. Выберите «Empty Activity» в качестве шаблона проекта и нажмите «Next».
3. Введите имя проекта и нажмите «Next».
4. Выберите «API 22: Android 5.1 (Lollipop)» в качестве «Minimum SDK» и нажмите «Next».
5. Выберите нужные опции и нажмите «Finish».

Проект будет создан с версией «compileSdkVersion 22» и «targetSdkVersion 22».
Если вы все еще будете получать кучу ошибок проверьте, конфигурацию вашего проекта, и прочитайте сообщения об ошибках для их решения.

Comment: Я так в принципе и создаю, но при Выберите «API 22: Android 5.1 (Lollipop)» в качестве «Minimum SDK» это не значит что Проект будет создан с версией «compileSdkVersion 22» и «targetSdkVersion 22»

Comment: В меню "File" выберите "Project Structure". Затем в окне "Project Structure" выберите вкладку "App" и измените значения "compileSdkVersion" и "targetSdkVersion" на "22". Далее нажмите кнопку "Apply" и "OK" чтобы сохранить изменения. Проверьте, что все зависимости и библиотеки, которые используются в вашем проекте, совместимы с API 22. После того, как вы удостоверитесь, что все зависимости и библиотеки корректны, выберите "Build" -> "Rebuild Project" из меню и подождите пока сборка завершится. Если все в порядке, то ваш проект должен успешно собраться и запуститься.

Comment: Похоже, проблема в том, что библиотеки и зависимости, которые использует ваш проект (такие как androidx.appcompat и androidx.lifecycle), требуют минимальной версии compileSdkVersion 32 или более поздней версии, но ваш проект в настоящее время настроен на компиляцию для Android-22.

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять какие библиотеки нужно использовать, пробовал использовать из старого проекта, но они не подходят

Comment: Выбор правильной версии библиотек и зависимостей может быть сложной задачей, особенно при попытке обеспечить обратную совместимость со старыми версиями Android. Попробуй проверить документацию или официальный сайт библиотеки. Многие библиотеки содержат список минимальных и рекомендуемых версий Android и других необходимых зависимостей. И еще проверить последнюю версию библиотеки и убедиться, что она совместима с целевой версией Android. Например, если вы ориентируетесь на Android 22, вам следует использовать последнюю версию библиотеки, совместимую с Android 22.

Comment: Вы также можете использовать отчет о зависимостях gradle, он предоставит вам зависимости, которые используются в вашем приложении, и их версии.

Вы можете использовать команду: gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency <dependency_name>, чтобы проверить версию зависимости.

Comment: Нашел старый проект но там с темой проблемы не подключаются, Видимо из за того что ранее подключение библиотек происходило через compile а сейчас через implementation

Comment: @soundsofnature вам верно посоветовали читать релиз ноты всех используемых библиотек в поисках подсказки какие версии нужно использовать. Тут основная проблема будет  том, что вам надо будет использовать древних предшественников либ из пакета `androidx`. Также, весьма вероятно, вам надо будет искать старую версию gradle и студии, чтобы всё это завелось. В общем сложная, долгая и неблагодарная работа. Весьма вероятно, что вам её вообще не стоит делать. Если вы это затеяли не ради эксперимента, то расскажите зачем - возможно вашу задачу можно решить иначе.